# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'xmlns'

Tags: c#, xml, soap, soapui, soap-client

Got Invalid content error:

```
 [Line -1: Column -1] cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'xmlns'.One of
      '{"urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com":Branch,
      "urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com":Customer,         
      "urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com":Product,
      "urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com":Event     
        }' is expected
```

I have generated the Reference class using the provided wsdl, while calling the service getting above error message. Following is my generated **Request XML** which I captured using Fiddler.

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ReqHeader  xmlns:h="http://www.citi.com.ssa/integration/Common/1.0"
                    xmlns="http://www.citi.com.ssa/integration/Common/1.0"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         
      <RequesterId>ABC</RequesterId>
      <TransactionId>TI20210203134601</TransactionId>
      <Timestamp>2021-02-03T13:46:01.0098901+03:00</Timestamp>
      <Lang>0</Lang>
    </h:ReqHeader>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CreateBillRequest xmlns="http://www.citi.com.ssa/integration/Billing/v1.0">
      <BillLetter xmlns="">
        <Context xmlns="urn:messages.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com">
          <Branch xmlns="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com">1010</Branch>
          <Customer xmlns="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com">TESTNAME</Customer>  
          <Team xsi:nil="true" xmlns="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com"/>
          <BehalfOfBranch xmlns="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com">1010</BehalfOfBranch>
          <Step xsi:nil="true" xmlns="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com"/>
        </Context>
        <FileIdentification xsi:nil="true" xmlns="urn:messages.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com"/>
        <MasterRef xsi:nil="true" xmlns="urn:messages.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com"/>
        <Applicant xmlns="urn:messages.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com">
          <Customer xmlns="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com">TESTNAME</Customer>         
          <Reference xsi:nil="true" xmlns="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com"/>
          <ZipCode xsi:nil="true" xmlns="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com"/>
          <Telephone xsi:nil="true" xmlns="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com"/>
          <FaxNumber xsi:nil="true" xmlns="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com"/>
          <TelexNumber xsi:nil="true" xmlns="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com"/>
          <Country xsi:nil="true" xmlns="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com"/>
          <TelexAnswerBack xsi:nil="true" xmlns="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com"/>
        </Applicant>
      </BillLetter>
    </CreateBillRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Following is the **Response XML:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:wsrr="http://citi.com/wsrr"
                xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math" 
                xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions" 
                xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header>
    <io:RespHeader xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                   xmlns:io="http://www.citi.com.ssa/integration/Common/1.0">
      <io:TransactionId/>
      <io:ReferenceNum>TI20210203134601</io:ReferenceNum>
      <io:Timestamp>2021-02-03T13:46:21.402</io:Timestamp>
      <io:Status>
        <io:StatusCode>999</io:StatusCode>        
        <io:TechDescription>
          [Line -1: Column -1] cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'xmlns'.One of
          '{"urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com":Branch,
          "urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com":Customer,         
          "urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com":Product,
          "urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com":Event     
            }' is expected.</io:TechDescription>
        <io:BusinessDescription>[Line -1: Column -1] cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'xmlns'. One of
        '{"urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com":Branch,
        "urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com":Customer,       
        "urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com":Product,
        "urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com":Event
         }' is expected.</io:BusinessDescription>
      </io:Status>
    </io:RespHeader>
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    <env:Fault>
      <faultcode>SEM.DAP.S002</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Backend:-simple-type 1: element {http://www.citi.com.ssa/integration/Common/1.0}TransactionId 
      of type {http://www.citi.com.ssa/integration/Common/System/1.0}C50_SType may not be empty</faultstring>
    </env:Fault>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Following is the Sample Request shared by Client which is working fine,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                     xmlns:ns="http://www.citi.com.ssa/integration/Common/1.0" 
                     xmlns:v1="http://www.citi.com.ssa/integration/Billing/v1.0" 
                     xmlns:urn="urn:messages.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com" 
                     xmlns:urn1="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com"
                     xmlns:urn2="urn:custom.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ns:ReqHeader>       
         <ns:RequesterId>CRM</ns:RequesterId>
         <ns:TransactionId>TQ20210105153701</ns:TransactionId>
         <ns:Timestamp>2021-01-05T17:37:01</ns:Timestamp>      
      </ns:ReqHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:CreateBillRequest xmlns:wsrr="http://citi.com/wsrr" xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math">
         <BillLetter>
            <urn:Context>
               <urn1:Branch>1010</urn1:Branch>
               <urn1:Customer>GEMNI</urn1:Customer>
               <urn1:Product>PV</urn1:Product>             
               <urn1:BehalfOfBranch>1010</urn1:BehalfOfBranch>
            </urn:Context>
            <urn:Applicant>
               <urn1:Customer>GEMNI</urn1:Customer>
               <urn1:NameAddress>Street 09 Stadium Road</urn1:NameAddress>
               <urn1:Telephone>+0123456789</urn1:Telephone>
               <urn1:FaxNumber>+0123456789</urn1:FaxNumber>
               <urn1:Email>J@citi.com.ssa</urn1:Email>
            </urn:Applicant>                    
         </BillLetter>
      </v1:CreateBillRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please suggest a fix.

Comment: Your namespaces in your request doesn't match the sample namespace.  Fix the namespaces.

Comment: Could you please point specific namespace, actually my Request doesn't have aliased namespaces,and In the sample request I don't know how they are calling the service which is generating the alias, Namespaces or schema are not altered by me it is all generated as per the Reference.cs class. Could you please help to identify the exact issue.

Comment: All the prefixes before the colons on the tag names.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have checked but I din't find any issue here.
do you mean,urn, urn1, urn2 !!! These are aliase created for namespaceURIs defined in the soapenv, following is from working xml request :

Comment: `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"      xmlns:ns="http://www.citi.com.ssa/integration/Common/1.0" 
xmlns:v1="http://www.citi.com.ssa/integration/Billing/v1.0"       xmlns:urn="urn:messages.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com"      xmlns:urn1="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com"      xmlns:urn2="urn:custom.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com">
           <urn:Context>
               <urn1:Branch>1010</urn1:Branch>
               <urn1:Customer>GEMNI</urn1:Customer>               
            </urn:Context>`

Comment: But the same namespaceURIs are inlined in My genetrated XML Request :
     ` <Context xmlns="urn:messages.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com">
          <Branch xmlns="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com">1010</Branch>
          <Customer xmlns="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com">TESTNAME</Customer>  
          <Team xsi:nil="true" xmlns="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com"/>
          <BehalfOfBranch xmlns="urn:common.service.tic.apps.tiplus3.misys.com">1010</BehalfOfBranch>
        </Context>`

Comment: You have :"<Context" while sample has "<urn:Context>".